# Can you increment a reactive var in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to increment reactive var in meteor?

For example:

```
var price = new ReactiveVar(0)

somefunction()=>{
price += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it's possible. Reactive vars would be pretty useless otherwise.

```js
const price = new ReactiveVar(0);

const somefunction = () => {
  price.set(price.get() + 5);
};
```

Useful link: [`ReactiveVar` documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html).

Comment: i figured it was possible, just my round about way of asking 'how. thank you.

Comment: @ZachFrotten You're welcome. I've updated my answer and added link to the documentation. Don't forget to accept my answer, btw.